# LuaLaTeX æquivalent to ucharclasses

Tags: luatex, ucharclasses

I am using the XeLaTeX ucharclasses package to switch language and font features on transition into the Greek and Latin unicode ranges. Is there a LuaLaTeX compatible alternative?

Comment: Is there a reason the edits got rolled back here? They all looked reasonable to me.

Comment: Is there any reason for preferring an obsolete spelling for “equivalent”? Also, *Unicode* is spelled with a capital “U”.

Comment: I will accept edits that leave my orthographic prædilections alone.